# Forcing a function to wait until another function is complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I am new to JavaScript and have been trying to get this working for a while now but to no success.

I have a function (task 3) that should only be executed after the functions before it finish. The functions before it (task 1 and 2) have more functions in them that fetch data from other sources and the time it takes for them is unknown. A wait function wouldn't really work because the time for task 1 and 2 could be very fast or very slow. I have tried doing an async/await setup but i must have done it wrong because it always completed task 3 before task 1 or 2. Same with a callback function which didn't actually callback it just did task 1 and 2 then never did task 3.

```
function task1(input){
   // has more functions that do other stuff

}
function task2(input){
   // has more functions that do other stuff
}
function task3(input){
   // this code should only be executed after both task 1 and 2 finish
}

function main(input1, input2, input3){
    task1(input1); // doesn't matter which task finishes first between 1 and 2
    task2(input2);
    task3(input3); // task 3 should not be executed until task 1 and 2 have completed.
}

main(input1, input2, input3);
```

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/promise/all

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What you're describing is synchronous code, and as presented, your code should execute each task in sequence.  Can you give us a little more detail into what each task is accomplishing?

Comment: task 1 and 2 fetch information from an Web API using fetch(), i'm right in believing fetch() is asynchronous right? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, and in that case each function would have to be an async function.  I'll try and put together a short answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use promises if you have asynchronous code. [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/promise/all) will wait for them all to be complete before running.

```js
function task1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("task 1")
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('foo');
    }, Math.random() * 2000);
  })
}

function task2() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("task 2")
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('bar');
    }, Math.random() * 2000);
  })
}

function task3() {
  console.log("task 3")
}

Promise.all([task1(), task2()]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
  task3()
});
```

Since you said you are using fetch, you can use that instead of promises since that returns a promise.

```
function task1() {
  return fetch('http://example.com/foo.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
}

function task2() {
  return fetch('http://example.com/bar.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
}

function task3() {
  console.log("task 3")
}

Promise.all([task1(), task2()]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
  task3()
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your environment supports async/await. So assuming that `task1` and `task2` either are `async` or return a `Promise`, then:

1. Use `await Promise.all` to wait for the two tasks to complete. This does not enforce any order, but will ensure both have completed before moving on.
2. Call `task3`.

```js
    async function task1(input){
       // has more functions that do other stuff

    }
    async function task2(input){
       // has more functions that do other stuff
    }

    function task3(input){
       // this code should only be executed after both task 1 and 2 finish
    }

    async function main(input1, input2, input3){
        await Promise.all(
            task1(input1),
            task2(input2)
        )
        task3(input3);
    }

    main(input1, input2, input3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're making API calls in your tasks, each task should be defined as an asynchronous function, and awaited as follows:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function task1(input){
  console.log(input)
  // API call goes here
  // const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/endpoint")
  console.log(response)
}
async function task2(input){
  console.log(input)
}
async function task3(input){
  console.log(input)
}

async function main(input1, input2, input3){
   await task1(input1); // doesn't matter which task finishes first between 1 and 2
   await task2(input2);
   await task3(input3); // task 3 should not be executed until task 1 and 2 have completed.
}

main("LIONS", "TIGERS", "BEARS")
```

You'll see the above results in:

```
LIONS
TIGERS
BEARS
```

and any API calls will occur in sequence.

Comment: Thanks, for responding but, it still didn't work. I don't know if it makes much of a difference but, in my code another two functions are called after the fetch. 
`fetch('website').then(task4()).then(task5()) `

task 4 and 5 also need to be done before task 3 but, they done return anything, they call another function in a loop depending on the information from the fetch.